# Instagram API - posting photos?

Tags: python-3.x, instagram, raspberry-pi3, instagram-api

I am currently working on an art project that would require an API to post images to Instagram. I was wondering if this API (https://github.com/GitTH/pigram) could be tweaked to post to Instagram from my Raspberry Pi's camera every time a motion sensor is activated?